# How to move outlook email attachments to smartsheet using Power Automate and Smartsheet API

Tags: outlook, power-automate, smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-2.0

I am currently working on a Power Automate flow that should take emails from a shared inbox and move them over to smartsheet along with their attachments.

Power Automate does not have a template to move attachments over to smartsheet, so I was going to use smartsheet's API to move the attachments over.

However, using the Smartsheet REST API and the contentBytes provided in Power Automate, it doesn't move attachments over properly and I am unable to view the file in smartsheet.

Below is the code i was using in Power Automate:

```
        "method": "POST",
        "uri": "https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/[sheetId]/rows/[rowId]/attachments",
        "headers":
        {
            "Content-Type": "['contentType']",
            "Content-Length": "['size']",
            "Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename=\"['name']\""
        },
        "body": "['contentBytes']",
```

This was in an "apply to each" method so it would work for each attachment.

My only guess is its cutting the contentBytes short somewhere so its not moving the full attachment over and thats why it cant be opened? But im not sure where to go from here.

[image]

Comment: Your screenshot shows [shetID] for the URI. You need to put in the actual sheet ID.

Comment: I did, I just put it there as a placeholder for the actual SheetId. the automation is putting the attachment exactly where i want it in smartsheet, but its unopenable.

Answer (score 0):

Power Automate has some problems while transporting the file meta.
Try add the file itself to a variable and transform the content of the file to a base64 content like below.

[image]

Comment: would I need to save the attachment as a file in sharepoint before I can add it to the variable?

Comment: Nop, you just have to make sure to inform the correct json structure and the contents in base64.

Comment: I tried this and it gave me an error if I set up the variable as an array, so I made it an object and it sent the attachment over to smartsheet but it still is unreadable. I entered it in how you have it and for "$content" used the formula `base64(body('Get_Attachment_(V2)')?['contentBytes'])` to ensure the email $content was in base64